# Lowering total requests per month on parse server Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server, parse-cloud-code, back4app

I am currently building an app that will run on parse server on back4app. I wanted to know if there are any tips for lowering requests. I feel like my current app setup is not taking advantage of any methods to lower requests.

For example: when i call a cloud code function is that one request even if the cloud code function has multiple queries in it? Can I use cloud code to lower requests some how?

another example : If I use parse local data store rather than constantly getting data from server can that lower requests or does it not really because you would still need to update changes later on. Or do all the changes get sent at once and count as one request.

Sorry I am very new to looking at how requests and back end pricing is measured in general. I want to make sure I can be as efficient as possible in order to get my app out without going over budget.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in this link here:
http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#performance

Most part of the tips there are useful both for performance and number of requests.

About your questions:
1) Cloud code - each call to a cloud code function counts as a single request, no matter how many queries you do
2) Client side cache - for sure it will reduce the total amount of requests you do in the server

Comment: If i call a cloud code function that call is one request. Now lets say that cloud code that i called has its own queries that are being called. you are sayinf those queries dont count as requests?

Comment: Precisely. Calling the Cloud function will count as 1 request even if it has many queries to run from the inside.